Unreal Plugin Copy files after package and archived to output path
I Created new plugin to use in my project, It can write file to fixed path.
After I package project to Output path. I can only way to copy folder to out path .
Has any way to copy folder out path when post package ?
I try to use "PostBuildSteps" Key at *.uplugin file.
but it is not same as visual studio post-build event. Do not contains "{OutDir}" variable.
and it will create new batch file named "postbuild-1.bat" ,but it not run automation.
